# How do I create a redirect route in Aurelia 2?

Tags: aurelia2

Let's say I want http://localhost/#/ to redirect to http://localhost/#/home, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by setting a default on the viewport:

```html
<au-viewport default="home"></au-viewport>
```

Comment: what does this do? send not found routes to #/home?

Comment: It sets the `home` component to the default component for the viewport, meaning that `home` will be loaded in the viewport when the viewport is rendered for the first time (and no other component is specified for the viewport in the url/navigation).